# Not able to get the element using any of the locator in JS or in Selenium. This is salesforce website. Looks like they have protected by some means

Tags: salesforce-lightning

[image]

I am using trying to get the input element through JS and fill some value there, But every time getElementByClassName() or getElementById() returns a null object.

Here is my javascript line
let x = document.querySelector("#combobox-input-196")

Below is the Selenium code
gotoSleep();
WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[placeholder='Search Customer Projects...']"));
inputField.sendKeys(code);

Selenium is throwing timeout exception saying, not able to locate the element.

Comment: Is there a different way to access "Lightning Web Components" through selenium?